# select checkboxes in sequential order for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

In my form

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id='up' value="go" name="move[up]" type="checkbox">
    <label for="up">Go</label>

    <input id='right' value="swing-r" name="move[right]" type="checkbox">
    <label for="right">Swing-Right</label>

    <input id='down' value="brake" name="move[down]" type="checkbox">
    <label for="down">Brake</label>

    <input id='left' value="swing-l" name="move[left]" type="checkbox">
    <label for="left">Swing-Left</label>

    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

i want to give each checkedbox a number for both selection and php array like

if clicked `go -> swing-l -> brake -> swing-r` the lables content will transform to

```
[1-Go] 
[2-Swing-Left]
[3-Brake] 
[4-Swing-Right]
```

by adding the number of the selection order, At the same time when i send the data i want the array to be ordered as the same order so it would be like

```
$move = [up => go, left => swing-l, down => brake, right => swing-r];
```

How to do that on my form exactly? i thinked about getting the `checkboxes` out of the `form` then put an `input` that contains the selected values, but couldn't figure how to do that wth my arrays names, Also while keeping the numbers ordered if it exists in the $_GET url as it is ordered.

Comment: there's only HTML and some PHP here; why the other tags?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought this will require some jquery or javascript knowledge, Or do i put tags only depending on my code?

Comment: Hard to say really. Maybe edit your post to ask if that is what you should use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do know that this will require some jquery, since i will order the selection in the DOM.

Comment: what do you mean by "if clicked go -> swing-l ->" what does -> mean ? is that mean we have to check all the checkbox ?

Comment: @Gagantous Not all, But just to be ordered as they've been checked, since if i checked it like this, i'll still get an array [up, right, down, left] even tho i selected in this order [up, left, down, right].

Comment: its mean we " have to" check all the check box but when we click submit, it return to array of the ordered as they've been checked ? so can we do like "swing-l -> go -> break" only ? for example i only checked 3 checkbox

Comment: @Gagantous Yes, You can do any combination, But it has to be in the same order it was checked after submittion. like if checked go->down we get [go, down], but if we checked down->go, we get [down, go] array.